# Esri JS api 3.11 stopped working with Chrome mobile

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dojo, esri, arcgis-js-api

I've encountered some strange behaviour after out Esri libraries were updated. My code stopped working on Google Chrome mobile browser. I took some code from official samples, and it still has same issue.

```
var esriMap = new Map(mapId, {
                basemap:"satellite",
                center :[-97.031, 37.638],
                zoom   :4,
                slider :false
              });


on(esriMap, "click", function(){
    alert("click esrimap");
});
```

Alert is displayed on Chrome emulator set to iPhone, on real iPhone. Not displayed on Nexus 5 with Chrome 38, on chrome emulator set to Nexus 5

Answer (score 1):

well, if you are using arcgis js api 3.14; in this case map has its own event binder, try that...

**Below is the working code:**

```
    var esriMap = new Map(mapId, {
            basemap:"satellite",
            center :[-97.031, 37.638],
            zoom   :4,
            slider :false
          });

       esriMap.on("click", lang.hitch(this, function (evt) {
                 alert("click esrimap");
            }));
```

Hope this will help you :)

Let me know if any clarifications required.